# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException problem with chromedriver version >74

Tags: python, selenium, action, webdriverwait, js-scrollintoview

I don't know why ActionChains `move_to_element()` is not working with chromedriver >74.

**(But it works on chromedriver 74 and geckodriver.)**

Even though I add these three line before ActionChains, it still failed to move to element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xxxxx)))
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xxxxx))
drvier.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

And throw error as below:

> selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message:
>   move target out of bounds   (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)

I also try to use move_to_element_with_offset mentioned in [Selenium MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException even after scrolling to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719535/selenium-movetargetoutofboundsexception-even-after-scrolling-to-element), it still not working:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 5, 5).click().perform()
```

Below is my setting of chromedriver.
Is there any settings impact to ActionChains?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Can you provide url?

Comment: What is your ChromeDriver version?

Comment: if you  perform scroll element for a click then don't need to scroll into view of the browser, you can perform js click and no need to scroll element   `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your use is to invoke `click()` through *ActionChains* instead of `presence_of_element_located()` and `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to use the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as **`element_to_be_clickable()`** as follows:

- Usage with *ActionChains*:

  ```
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))).click().perform()
  ```
- If you have to `scrollIntoView()` before invoking `click()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xxxxx))
  drvier.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xxxxx)))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))).click().perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Update

As per your comments that:

```
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
```

worked for you, but as per the *Release Notes* of [ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt):

> Resolved issue 2536: Make standards mode (goog:chromeOptions.w3c:true) the default [Pri-2]

**`ChromeDriver 75.0`** solves this issue.

So the bottom line is, `chromeOptions.w3c` needs to be set as **`true`** by default. It will be against the best practices to turn off `w3c` in *chromedriver* to address the error. We have discussed this in length and breadth in the following discussions:

- [How to turn off w3c in chromedriver to address the error unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452798/how-to-turn-off-w3c-in-chromedriver-to-address-the-error-unknown-command-cannot/56457780#56457780)
- [Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError) with Selenium ChromeDriver in Cucumber Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111529/cannot-call-non-w3c-standard-command-while-in-w3c-mode-seleniumwebdrivererr/56456696#56456696)

Comment: The exception is on the `move_to_element`, it has nothing to do with the click.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry to ask the fool question. I found that it caused by Chromedriver 75 runs in W3C standard compliant mode by default. And I found the solution with add  "options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)" , it works well with ActionChains.
Release note: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt

Comment: @Yun Checkout the answer update and let me know if any questions.

Comment: I have updated chromedriver to 79 and tried to set w3c to true. It still failed to use ActionChains move_to_element().

Comment: @Yun I tried my best with a canonical answer with reference to all the relevant discussions, call is yours now what works for you :)

Comment: Note. In my case (chrome driver 80) , adding the first JavaScript execute works because `move_to_element` moves to the center of the element instead of the top; while `click` requires the top to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

`move_to_element` uses internally `move_to`

```
def move_to_element(self, to_element):
    if self._driver.w3c: # default in chromedriver 79
        self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element)

def move_to(self, element, x=None, y=None):
    #...
    el_rect = element.rect
    left_offset = el_rect['width'] / 2
    top_offset = el_rect['height'] / 2
    left = -left_offset + (x or 0)
    top = -top_offset + (y or 0)

    self.source.create_pointer_move(origin=element, x=int(left), y=int(top))
```

The mouse pointer is moved by offset based on the element position. You are locating the element and then scroll it into view using JavaScript, so the offset is calculated by the wrong coordinates.

Removing the JavaScript scroll should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Neither of js scroll or not can be working. And I found that it can solve by setting w3c to False.