# Why am I getting a MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException for coordinates within the viewport? How to fix?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, selenium-chromedriver

Using the following code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/canvas')
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 185, -35).click().perform()
```

I am unable to navagate to the desired section of a canvas element and receive this error:

```
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

My move target is most definitely within the viewport, no scrolling is necessary to make it clickable. I am using chromedriver and am using the top left corner of the canvas as the start point for my pixel coordinates for `move_to_element_with_offset()`. Any ideas to fix this? I'm interested in any solutions to click a specified point on a canvas in python, doesn't need to use this same method.

Comment: Depending on your chromedriver version it could be top left or the center after version 75.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819502/movetargetoutofboundsexception-problem-with-chromedriver-version-74 check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### move_to_element_with_offset()

[`move_to_element_with_offset()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset) moves the mouse by an offset of the specified element where offsets are relative to the top-left corner of the element.

So from the top-left corner of the `<canvas>` element if you intent to move by offset `(185, -35)` where:

- 185 units to the right
- 35 units upwards

will be always result into `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`.

---

### Solution

Instead of a negative offset to move upwards you can use a possitive offset to move downwards as follows:

```
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 35, 35).click().perform()
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException problem with chromedriver version >74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819502/movetargetoutofboundsexception-problem-with-chromedriver-version-74/59819602#59819602)